The capacitance value written on reactive ballast
I have recently opened a "traditional" fluorescent light circuit for the first time. It has three main components: A 120 cm long lamp, a 1 H reactive ballast, and a non-electronic starter. Among the markings on the ballast, I can see "\$C=3.4\; \mu\text{F}\$". What does it mean?
I guess this capacitor is intended for improving the power factor. But where is it? The only capacitor I'm aware of is the capacitor inside the starter. Its capacitance is about 1 nF only (measured with multi-meter).

It means that for the rated voltage, frequency and lamp, you need 3.4 µF across line-neutral for power factor correction due to the inductive load from your lamp+ballast. It's not clear to what exact PF (this seems to differ between markets), but usually >0.9.
